# Area 51 Proposal for Finance (including Behavioural, Corporate, Public Finance)

Tags: discussion, area51

Please let me know if this is fine. In view of the tags economics and finance here (in a mathematical setting), I thought to promote this Area 51 Proposal here. I hope this is appropriate because I feel mathematics and finance are interrelated.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65253/finance-including-behavioural-corporate-public-finance

Comment: I suppose that you are aware that there was a proposal for [Economics.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics) which was not successful. See also this older post: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4049/economics-se-is-closing-can-we-salvage-some-of-the-questions/ (Some other related sites are mentioned there.)